# Select options based on percentage

Tags: javascript, algorithm, html5-canvas

I need an efficient method to select options based on percentages.

For example, assume we have four colors: black, blue, red and white.

Now, I'm going to create an array filled with colors, except, I need to select them based on the following percentages:

```
Black - 80% chance of selection
Blue - 70% chance of selection
Red - 30% chance of selection
White - 5% chance of selection
```

I thought of assigning a range between 1 and 100 to each color and then generating a random number between. This however means the % of all colors has to add up to 100%, which, might not be avoidable really.

Code not necessary but would love some algorithms that can be implemented via JavaScript to accomplish this.

EDIT:
Based on [Patrice Levesque's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2397004/patrice-levesque) answer, I created [this test](http://jsbin.com/ayigeb/3/edit). While I haven't verified the statistics of it, it visually represents what I'm after. As usual, I over-thought the problem. Other answers are more than welcome.

Comment: How long is your initial array ?

Comment: @karthikr probably a 6 x 6 grid or maybe 6 X 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to normalize your values; get the total “percentage” (in your instance, 80 + 70 + 30 + 5 → 185) and pick a number between 1 and that total; in your case, 1-80 would be black, 81-150 would be blue, 151-180 would be red and 181-185 white.

Comment: Thanks. I created a test case (linked in my question) to visually represent this.